# ARM926ej-s header instructions and the reality comparison

Tags: assembly, header, arm

When dealing with ARM926ej-s microcontroler there are still some uncertainties with a header which was supposed to be like this:

[image]

But in the boot program it is written like this:

```
__start:                                               /*label - allso an entry point*/
arm926ejs_reset:                                       /*label*/
    B     arm926ejs_reset_handler                      /*header - vector (0x00)*/
    .word   0x41676d69                                 /*header - magic (0x04)*/
    .word   0,0,0,0,0                                  /*header - execution_crc32 + Reserved0 (0x08)*/
image_type:                                            /*label*/
    .word   0x0000000A                                 /*header - ImageType (0x1C)*/
sizeOfPermanentCode:                                   /*label*/
    .word   (__image_size)                             /*header - ImageLength (0x20)/
    .word   0,0                                        /*header - ReleaseID + buildTime (0x24)*/
bootparameter:                                         /*label*/
    .word   0                                          /*sbzBootParameter (0x2C)*/
    .word   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    /*cust_reserved + header_crc32 + Reserved1 (0x30)*/

arm926ejs_reset_handler:
```

1st i need to know how is it possible that labels don't take space? If i take this into consideration adresses match perfectly with a supplied picture. But I wonder why is there so many 0? Don't we need to specify something so that the header is valid?

Thanks.

Comment: A label doesn exist in memory. It's just a name for an address for convenience of human readers, so they don't take space.

Comment: you can have multiple labels wherever, they dont take space as Devolus said, they are a way to extract an address of whatever immediately follows them.  image_type can be used in the code to represent the address of the .word 0x000A that follows it.

Comment: Thank you now i can see this :)